# Ignoring non-existent org-mode agenda files

Tags: org-mode

In my current setup, I sometimes start emacs with some directories in which I keep my org-mode files, not existing. I.e. for work I use encrypted files, so for example, my `~/projects/foobar/notes` doesn't exist, because my `~/projects/foobar` directory is empty (because the disk is not mounted into it).

Because of that, when I start emacs and my `~/projects/foobar` it not mounted, I get the message:

```
Non-existent agenda file `~/projects/foobar/notes`. [R]emove from list or [A]bort?
```

And both options are no good. `Abort` it obviously not what I want, and `Remove` removes the directory permamently (by adding `org-agenda-files` into `custom-set-variables` section without that directory), so when I later run emacs with disk mounted, the files are not loaded. I need to edit my emacs config, remove that automatically added `org-agenda-files` in `custom-set-variables` section, save, exit, restart emacs.

Is there a way to tell org-mode to ignore if the file doesn't exist and just proceed with the files which exists? Ideally, they would be picked up after I refresh agenda, but I can live with being forced to reinitialize my agenda (`C-c a a`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customize `org-agenda-skip-unavailable-files` and set it to `t`.

`C-h v org-agenda-skip-unavailable-files` says (note that I've customized my setting to `t` already):

```
org-agenda-skip-unavailable-files is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.

Its value is t
Original value was nil

Non-nil means to just skip non-reachable files in ‘org-agenda-files’.
A nil value means to remove them, after a query, from the list.
```